# Can we execute the AsyncTask in onPostExecute()?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my android activity I have one asynctask that downloads the HTML stuff of some url. However if there is something wrong with the website, it(doInbackground()) just returns the string "error" to the onPostExecute(). The onPostExecute method checks the returned string. If the returned string is not "error", then it does some other work else I want it to execute the asynctask for another url.

Is this a good thing to do?

Here is the AsyncTask code:

```
    private class DataLoader extends AsyncTask<URL,Integer,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //some Stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... url) {
        try {
            Document d = Jsoup.connect(url[0].toString()).timeout(0).get();
            String docString = d.toString();

            return docString;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return "error";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                     if(!(result == "error")){
                             //Process the result
                     }
                     else{
                       DataLoader g = new DataLoader();

            try {
                g.execute(new URL("http://workingexample.com/"));
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                     }

    }
}
```

Comment: do you think there is any benefit in calling another asynctas? you can  try to connect the other link in doinbackground

Comment: What do you mean by connect? I couldn't get it.

Comment: you can do it in same doInBackground itself..why do u need to call the AsyncTask again to do this..post ur AsyncTask code..

Answer (score 1):

I think StinePike and bakriOnFire mean something like this

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(URL... url) {
    String docString = downloadHTML(url[0].toString());

    // Try another url
    if (docString.equals("error")) {
        docString = downloadHTML("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
    // Try another url
    if (docString.equals("error")) {
        docString = downloadHTML("http://google.com");
    }

    return docString;
}

private String downloadHTML(String url) {
    String docString = null;
    try {
        Document d = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
        docString = d.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        docString ="error";
    }
    return docString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Stefan Leisenberger's answer has the right idea, although I think it might be neater if you provided all of the URLs in the `execute` call, and then just processed them in a loop in your `doInBackground` method.

So the `doInBackground` method could look something like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
  int count = urls.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    try {
      Document d = Jsoup.connect(urls[i].toString()).timeout(0).get();
      String docString = d.toString();
      return docString;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return "error"; // None of the URLs worked.
}
```

And then your `execute` call would need to look something like this:

```
DataLoader g = new DataLoader();
g.execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Answer (score 0):

onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods are on UiThread, so yes you can do whatever you want to do there. Only doInBackground method is another thread so you better not to do anything will affect ui, but else would be ok.